# Use drawable make button

Tags: android, imageview

Because I want make on click picture, when I add sourcecode:  "setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()", it's has some error? but I don't know what's happen?

Is have any one can give some suggest?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[] countries = new String[] {

        "South Korea",
        "Japan"
};

int[] flags = new int[]{

        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher
};

int[] flags1 = new int[]{

        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher
};


String[] currency = new String[]{

        "South Korean Won",
        "Japanese Yen"
    };

private ImageView test1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();      
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
            hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) ); 
            hm.put("flag1", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );  
            aList.add(hm);        
        }
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" ,"flag1"};   
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur,R.id.flag1}; 
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.row, from, to);
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);   
        **ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);
        imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: could you please post the logcat too..

Comment: You are doing `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)` and accessing your arrays like `currency[i]` but your arrays length is __2__, so it will raise a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Also, post your `xml` if the error occurs when you `setOnClickListener`.

Comment: this is my log: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.food12/com.example.food12.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)